# Git error when checking out a file that wasn't changed by git: error: pathspec 'web/.htaccess' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git, shell, sh

I am creating a Shell Script which runs git commands on my test server as part of my continuous integration workflow.

The process is very simple, I have to run a test file (./run_test_code.sh) and commit the results in a new branch.

```
#Something like this:
$ ./run_test_code.sh
```

That code modifies lots of files and **some times** modify configuration files that I am not interested to change as part of the testing process, ie: .htaccess file

Therefore, I have included one extra step:

```
# So, if the .htaccess is modified by ./run_test_code.sh, I can bring back the latest version using git checkout
$ git checkout web/.htaccess
```

However, the problem I am getting with this is that **IF** the .htaccess file is modified, the script works very well. In contrast, **IF** the .htaccess is not modified, then I got the following error:

```
$ git checkout web/.htaccess
error: pathspec 'web/.htaccess' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

Thus, My question is:
Is there any way I can detect using Shell Commands if the .htaccess file has been modified before running git checkout web/.htaccess?

Thanks

Comment: Try `git checkout HEAD -- web/.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing more testing and I was using git reset instead of checkout.

`$ git reset web/.htaccess`

And it works **IF** the file exists or it has been modified. However, **IF** the file is not modified, then I got this error:

```
$ git reset web/.gitignore
fatal: ambiguous argument 'web/.gitignore': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

All I need is to reset the .gitignore and .htaccess regardless if they have been modified or not.

Any ideas?

Thanks